How to override Datadog sampling rules for all errors in Java using DD_TRACE environment variables?
I have a Java Spring application that is integrated in datadog APM. I want to reduce the sampling rate for traces to 10%. However, if a trace is from an error, I want it to be included all the time. How can I add this override using the DD_TRACE environment variables?
The environment variables I use to set the current sampling rule for traces is DD_TRACE_SAMPLING_RULES, however as far as I know I can only include a JSNON object with the service name and the sampling rate. There is no option to add a rule to override this sampling rate for errors.

See the documentation for ingesting error and rare traces.
The env var you are after is this one:
@env DD_APM_ERROR_TPS - integer - optional - default: 10

